# Implicit intents with startService are not safe

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to figure out in app billing. Android developer docs (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service) say to bind the service like

```
bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), 
                       mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

but that line is generating a warning `Implicit intents with startService are not safe`. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: `bindService()` will throw an exception if you try to use an implicit `Intent` on the "L" Developer Preview. If that behavior will be retained when the next version of Android ships, then Google's in-app billing code will need to be changed, probably within the next couple of months. As I don't use in-app billing, I don't know if there is a documented secure workaround. For more background on the issues, read http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/29/dealing-deprecations-bindservice.html and http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/09/26/android-exported-service-mitm-attacks.html